# How not to use Google Analytics cookies on Blogger?

Tags: google-analytics, blogger, cookie

I just noticed of a blog powered by Blogger which doesn't store any cookie, and therefore, doesn't need to show the annoying cookie popup.

Checking Blogger options, I don't see anywhere where to get rid of Google Analytics cookies. So... how did they do so?

Answer (score 2):

Analytics is not enabled by default.   Blogger only uses Google Analytics if the owner has either installed GA tracking code, or entered a GA ID in the settings.    If neither of these is done, then there are no analytics gathered for the blog (as far as the owner knows).